# Show Hide div if, if statement is true

Tags: php, jquery, html, hide, show

My code works to a point. What I want is that when this if statement is false, the `<div>` doesn't show

```
<?php
    $query3 = mysql_query($query3);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query3);
    if ($numrows > 0) {
        $fvisit = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
    }
    else {
    }
?>
```

Comment: Which `<div>` shouldn't show? I only see some PHP.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use css or js for hiding a div. In else statement you can write it as:

```
else{
?>
<style type="text/css">#divId{
display:none;
}</style>
<?php
}
```

Or in jQuery

```
else{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">$('#divId').hide()</script>
<?php
}
```

Or in javascript

```
else{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('divId').style.display = 'none';</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Why `?>` and then `<?php` ?

Comment: Does the js file need to be linked to the php file?

Comment: Why `?>` and then `<?php` ?  ?

Comment: original question wants to hide the div in PHP ELSE statement. First, I am closing the PHP with ?> and then adding JS/CSS/jQuery code. After that I am again opening the PHP(with <?php ) for closing the else bracket ( } ).

Answer (score 11):

This does not need jquery, you could set a variable inside the if and use it in html or pass it thru your template system if any

```
<?php
$showDivFlag=false
$query3 = mysql_query($query3);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query3);
if ($numrows > 0){
    $fvisit = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
    $showDivFlag=true;
 }else {

 }

?>
```

later in html

```
  <div id="results" <?php if ($showDivFlag===false){?>style="display:none"<?php } ?>>
```

Answer (score 6):

A fresh look at this(possibly)
in your php:

```
else{
      $hidemydiv = "hide";
}
```

---

And then later in your html code:

```
<div class='<?php echo $hidemydiv ?>' > maybe show or hide this</div>
```

in this way your php remains quite clean

Answer (score 4):

Use show/hide method as below

```
$("div").show();//To Show

$("div").hide();//To Hide
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$divStyle=''; // show div

// add condition
if($variable == '1'){
  $divStyle='style="display:none;"'; //hide div
}

print'<div '.$divStyle.'>Div to hide</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest to hide a div and show a div in PHP based on a variables and the operator.

```
<?php 
$query3 = mysql_query($query3);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query3);
?>
<html>
<?php if($numrows > null){ ?>
     no meow :-(
<?php } ?>

<?php if($numrows < null){ ?>
     lots of meow
<?php } ?>
</html>
```

Here is my original code before adding your requirements:

```
<?php 
$address = 'meow';
?>
<?php if($address == null){ ?>
     no meow :-(
<?php } ?>

<?php if($address != null){ ?>
     lots of meow
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

from php you can invoke jquery like this but my 2nd method is much cleaner and better for php

```
if($switchView) :?>
 <script>$('.container').hide();</script>
 <script>$('.confirm').show();</script>
<?php endif;
```

another way is to initiate your class and dynamically invoke the condition like this

```
$registerForm ='block';
```

then  in your html use this

```
<div class="col" style="display: <?= $registerForm?>">
```

now you can play with the view with if and else easily without having a messed code example

```
if($condition)  registerForm = 'none';
```

Make sure you use 'block' to show and 'none' to hide. This is far the easiest way with php

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the whole block within the `<?php ?>` tags in the initial 'if' statement and don't specify an 'else', this condition is not satisfied, returns false so therefore won't display the `<div>`