# Hiding a div upon login with php

Tags: php, html, show-hide

I am trying to hide a div once a user has logged into there account of my online store (built with cartweaver 4 php) but i just cant seem to get it to work.

the php code for defining wether the user is logged in or not is as followed:

```
if(!strlen($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]) ||
    $_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"] === 0 ||
    $_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"] === "0" ||
    $_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerType"] == 0 ||
    (isset($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerCheckout"]) &&
       strtolower($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerCheckout"]) == "guest"))
```

and the div i would like to hide upon login, which contains a table, have been given an id and class of:

```
  <div id="newcustomertable" class='newcustomer'>
```

I have tried applying this method using css: [Show Hide div if, if statement is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020873/show-hide-div-if-if-statement-is-true)

but that ended up giving me an undefined variable error on my testing server.

I admit i am a bit of a php newbie, so if anyone who is able to make more sense of this could help out and possibly find a solution it would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked to see if those sessions are defined with isset()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id ="newcustomertable"></div>
<?
if(!isset($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]) || 
!strlen(@$_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]) ||
@$_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"] === 0 ||
@$_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerType"] == 0 ||
(isset($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerCheckout"]) &&
strtolower(@$_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerCheckout"]) == "guest"))
{
?>
<script>
document.getElementById("newcustomertable").style.display = "none";
</script>
<?  
}
?>
```

Make sure that the condition check is AFTER the div element getting rendered. Because if you put it before the element the page would not have fully rendered and so the script will not be able to get the div that you want to hide.

REVERSE Condition based on OP's request. I know this is a kluge, folks. Dont flame me!

```
<div id ="newcustomertable"></div>
<?
if(!isset($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]) || 
!strlen(@$_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]) ||
@$_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"] === 0 ||
@$_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerType"] == 0 ||
(isset($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerCheckout"]) &&
strtolower(@$_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerCheckout"]) == "guest"))
{
 //do nothing
}
else
{
?>
<script>
document.getElementById("newcustomertable").style.display = "none";
</script>
<?  
}
?>
```

Comment: was adding, clicked submit answer by mistake.. patience!! :P

Comment: tried your sollution, xampp gives this error on line 80: Undefined index: cwCustomerID

line 80: if(!strlen(@$_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]) ||

Comment: Looks like error suppression does not work in your server. I have updated code. Check my answer above:

Comment: still getting an error on this line:

if(!isset($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]) && !strlen(@$_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]) ||

Comment: hang on, seems i may have re-used the old code before you updated it. however now the div is initially hidden, and then shown again on login. seems to be giving the opposite effect

Comment: Well that is a problem with the conditions you have in the `if` statement. I am sure you can sort them out now that you know how to show/hide the div. As an easy way, you can just move the whole snippet of `<script>..</script>` to the else part of the condition and that will reverse the effect back. So the code will be something like:

`if(condition)
{
//do nothing
}
else
{
//move the javascript here
}`

Again, this is a kludge, but I think it will do the task

Comment: im sorry for the newbieness but i couldnt quite get that figured out. If you wouldnt mind would you be able to update the answer with what i should use?

Comment: Dont be sorry. We all were (and still are) newbies :) I have updated the code in my answer, see if that works. And remember it is not the safest, best solution - I am just trying to get things working for you

Comment: Well i can happily say it works! For me this will do fine. I appreciate your time and help :)

Comment: See? this makes it worth all the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got at least 3 variables there that could be throwing your undefined variable warning:

```
$_SESSION["cwclient"]
$_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]
$_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerType"]
```

you need to isset() each of those before doing any tests.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the strlen function in PHP returns an INT, not a boolean.

Change from:

```
(!strlen($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"])
```

to:

```
(strlen($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]) > 0)
```

Comment: I guess that's true, not my coding style but works appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

First of all could that not just be simplified to the following if statement to make it easier

```
 if (($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]<>NULL)&&($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerCheckout"]) == "guest")) { 
#code here 
}
```

Second of all to hide the div if they are logged in you could do it like this

```
     if (($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]<>NULL)&&($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerCheckout"]) == "guest")) { 
    $shouldhide="style='visibility:hidden;'";
    } else {
$shouldhide=""; 
}
echo"<div id='hidethis' $shouldhide>";
```

Although if the content is a security risk it'd be better to not output it at all as it's still visible in the source code.

Comment: would i then rename the div id to 'hidethis'?

Comment: Sorry I should of clarified the div ID doesn't matter in this example that was just to illustrate that div will be hidden, all that matters is the variable $shouldhide as this may or may not add a style rule of hidden depending on whether they are logged in or not

Comment: right..well whats happening now is the reverse effect. After i login everything on the page is hidden except for the div.

Comment: could you post the code so we can see what's wrong with it please! That sounds very strange indeed

Comment: well first of all your shortened version produced a syntax error both on the if condition line and the "else" line:

if (!strlen($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"]) || $_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"] === 1 || $_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerID"] === "1" || $_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerType"] == 1 || (isset($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerCheckout"]) && strtolower($_SESSION["cwclient"]["cwCustomerCheckout"]) == "guest")) { 
    $shouldhide="style='visibility:hidden;'";
    } else {
$shouldhide=""; 
}
echo"<div id='hidethis' $shouldhide>";