# load a div after a login form posts to php and login details are validated by the php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a login.php file using jQuery and html. The standard form section of the page loads is loaded as a div which, after posting to the same page, should replace the existing div with a different div to show that one is logged in. I don't want to build a new, different page to achieve this as I wish to save on loading time.

```
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
$('#target').load('LoginForm.html'); //loads standard form (below). OK
};
</script>
<script src="jQuery.js"></script>
</head>

<?php # Script 16.8 - login.php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
//here I intend to have code to validate the post
//if all is OK then allow the new div to load.
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#target').load('NewPageIntoDiv.html');
</script>
<?php

} // End of SUBMIT conditional.
?>
<body>
<div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The form code is standard:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <p><b>Email Address:</b> <input type="text" name="email" size="20" maxlength="40" /></p>
    <p><b>Password:</b> <input type="password" name="pass" size="20" maxlength="20" /></p>
    <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton" onClick="" class="button"/></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

In my trials I got it to load the div direct from the submit button but this does not allow for validation and database referencing etc. So I need it to load after the php has checked the POSTed info. Researched here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020873/show-hide-div-if-if-statement-is-true
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/some-things-you-should-know-about-ajax/
http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development/4718-calling-javascript-function-php-post2108017.html
```

Result: On submit only the values in the form boxes disappear the form stays visible. I need it to load the NewPageIntoDiv.html Help/suggestions appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why is there an `'` in the script ending tag? </script>'

Comment: @Akshay Thank you. A typeO, sorry. My trials did not have that. Rechecked trials and now question is edited.

Answer (score 0):

So good start so far. Somethings have to change to accomplish interactivity with your PHP Web app:

- Clean your code, scripts should go at the bottom of your document.
- Use a different event handler.

I've done the same thing without a framework. Consider using the same div to load content.

If you want to avoid any security issues with the login session consider using  [OAuth2](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/).  It will save your users the problem of having to remember another user_id and password. It keeps you from having to secure authenticated user info.

This has already been answered check it: [How to load a PHP file into a div](http://www.google.com/urlhttp://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAAahUKEwjbyIyS_tvIAhWEPCYKHctyCA8&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F12524228%2Fhow-to-load-php-file-into-div-by-jquery&usg=AFQjCNHasaJF1LQ7bHZlL9yBrq5Pd137fw&sig2=zjgPf_60sQCbUiFyI6pR_A)

Comment: The 'How to load a PHP file into a div' does not work. But I have followed this up in a general search in 'Stackoverflow' but there is nothing specific about using the POST method. I can get it to work from a button click as said above. Meanwhile I will follow up your other suggestions. Thank you indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was getting the form section of index.php  to go to a separate login.php page (that is not seen in the process of logging in) then come back to index.php if all is OK with the validation and load a different div 'sectionbase1.html' where the form.html was.

```
<?php # Script 16.6 - index.php
require_once ('includes/config.inc.php');
include ('includes/header.html');// This includes session start.
?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script src="jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav1>
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { //session variable set from login.php
include('menuIn.html'); // menu displayed when logged in
?>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
$('#target').load('sectionbase1.html');//loaded into target div below when logged in
};
</script>
<?php
}else{
include('menuOut.html'); //menu displayed when logged out
?>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
$('#target').load('sectionindex.html'); //loaded into div below when not logged in.
};
</script>
<?php
}
?>
</nav1>
</header>
<div id="target"></div>
<script src="AjaxLoad.js"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

The form code is standard see above in top question and is loaded into the div as 'sectionindex.html' Next:

```
<?php # Script 16.6 - login.php
require_once ('includes/config.inc.php');
include ('includes/header.html');
//Not included is my validation and database checked until finally....
//and the Session variable is set here too.
$_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
//Then finally..... if all is valid etc. Go back to index.php
$url = BASE_URL . 'index.php'; // BASE_URL is my site name www.example.com
ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
header("Location: $url");
exit(); 
?>
```

The AjaxLoad.js is used to load the the menu links into the div when clicked

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#target').load(url);
  return false;
});
```

menuOut.html is below, menuIn.html is much the same but with some different links

```
<ul>
<li><a href="sectionindex.html" class="trigger">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="sectionpricing.html" class="trigger">Pricing</a></li>
<li><a href="sectionFAQ.html" class="trigger">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="sectionAboutUs.html" class="trigger">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="sectionlogin.html" class="trigger">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="sectionregister.html" class="trigger">Sign In</a></li>
<li><a href="sectionhelp.html" class="trigger">How It Works</a></li>
</ul>
```

Each link is added as a div, see below, to the index.php using the AjaxLoad.js script and the separate menus are added to  using the $_SESSION 'user_id' (this variable is particular to my set-up and database. You would have to user one suitable to your application.

```
<div id="target"></div>
```