# If statement giving error php

Tags: php

I'm very new in PhP and trying to modify the code of may website.

I want to display a line only under certain condition but when I use if in the code, the site is showing blank

Thanks for your support

```
<?php 
if ( $property->post_type != 'land')
{
    <div class="property-drow">                                          
    <span>
<?php 
    if($site_language=='en_US') { 
        echo 'Age of Construction'; 
    } else { 
        echo 'Âge Construction'; 
    }
?>
    </span><p> {echo $construction;} ?></p>
    </div>
}?>
```

Comment: it would be easier to hide using css : see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020873/show-hide-div-if-if-statement-is-true (but there's an error in your php syntax.. paste it into  https://phpcodechecker.com/ and it's report an error..)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best answer would be to tell you to add some error reporting to your code as you test

Add to the top of your file(s) *while testing* right after your opening PHP tag for example

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// normal code
```

In this case you are not starting and stopping the PHP interpreter in the right places

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if ( $property->post_type != 'land')
{
?>
    <div class="property-drow">                                          
        <span>
<?php 
    if($site_language=='en_US') { 
        echo 'Age of Construction'; 
    } else { 
        echo 'Âge Construction'; 
    }

?>
        </span>
        <p> <?php echo $construction;?></p>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some html escaping issues.

To dry up your code you could consider using the ternary operator and short echo tag:

```
<?php if ($property->post_type != 'land'): ?>
    <div class="property-drow">
        <span><?=
        $site_language=='en_US' 
        ? 'Age of Construction' 
        : 'Âge Construction'
        ?></span><p><?= $construction ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```