# Hide the element if product is in a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress

How could I hide element button in my case if the product is in specific category ?
I have tried

```
<div id="buttonid"  if ( has_term( "category", "product_cat", $post->ID ) ) { echo 'style="display:none;"' }?>></div>

</div>
```

Comment: You have not actually _styled_ anything here, you have just written text content into a div element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show Hide div if, if statement is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020873/show-hide-div-if-if-statement-is-true)

Comment: simple query can solve your issue `where category != 'product_cat'` or array filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You missed php syntax:

```
<div id="buttonid"<?php if ( has_term( "category", "product_cat", $post->ID ) ) { echo 'style=" display:none;"'; }?>></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a condition on the button to not display in the specified category.If you want to do it by style

```
<?php if (has_term( "category", "product_cat", $post->ID ) ) { ?>
    <style>
      #buttonid{display:none;}
    </style>
<?php }?>

<div id="buttonid">
 <button>Save</button>
</div>
```